# Detecting activex object using modernizr

Tags: javascript

How to detect activex object using modernizr?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think modernizr has a built-in test for activeX (`activeX` have nothing to do with *modern development*, and modernizr checks mainly for new `API` support on browsers, CSS3 and HTML5 features)

just try using your own custom function like this:

```
function activeXSupport(o) {
   try {
     return new ActiveXObject(o);
   }
   catch(e) { return false; } 
}

...

if (activeXSupport("Microsoft.yourActiveXObject")) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: If you need the CSS classes you can do this :

`Modernizr.addTest(THE TEST);`